# Call navigation icon click in toolbar (android)

Tags: android, call, onclicklistener, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have code below:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

and XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I want to call click on navigation icon of toolbar, but i cant find method to do it.
I can't call onClickListener(null) because I change icon inside onClick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this by replacing 'number' with the index of the icon. (It could be 1-2-3-4 etc.)

```
    toolbar.getChildAt(number).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do whatever you want here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Toolbar toolbar;

toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used setNavigationOnClickListener {} for this.

```
// I used private function here, you don't need to.
private fun onBackArrowPressed() {
    // when user clicked the navigation icon (here is back arrow)
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        // find the nav controller and pop backstack
        findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
}
```

[Material Components Android Top AppBar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TopAppBar.md)

Comment: Please add some context/explanation around the answer